# When using gdb, how to print a part of values in array in Pascal

Tags: arrays, debugging, gdb, pascal

We know, in C language, if there is an array

```
int data[100];
```

then ,in gdb, we can print data[4] to data[14] by typing:

```
print *(data+4)@11
```

so, the question is: when we program in Pascal language, we may have an array:

```
var
   data: array[0..100] of Integer;
```

when we debug it in gdb, how can we print the value from data[4] to data[14]?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I never tried, but what makes you think that would be different? I guess you should be able to use the same syntax. What have you tried?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis @data[4]^@11 but failed. I had struggled for hours.

Comment: But that **is** a different syntax. What happens if you use the original `*(data+4)@11`?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis A parse error in expression,  near '(data+4)@11'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this when gdb's language is set to Pascal -- nobody ever implemented this extension in the Pascal expression parser.

One workaround is to print the address of the array, then temporarily switch the language to C and `print *(type *)addr @ ...`.

Another workaround would be to write a new gdb command (either using the CLI or using Python) that does what you like.  Or, if you are doing a lot of Pascal debugging, you could implement this extension in gdb -- it isn't hard.